# How to check given value is present inside given array with ignoreCase in php?

Tags: php, laravel, case-sensitive

I have one Array which contain two elements, i am taking input from the user from the API request parameters sometimes it contains `capital and small` letters ,based on that i am writing some conditions ,Now what my requirement is if user enters  small letters  also it should match the given array please help me to fix the issue..

```
$array=['Admin','Root'];

if(in_array($request->role,$array)){
if($request->role== 'Admin'){
     //my logic
  }
}
```

**URL-1:-**
in this scenario it passes the condition

/v1/Users?role=Admin

**URL-2:-**
/v1/Users?role=admin

this scenario fails , i need to pass this scenario also

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the string using `strtolower()` php [function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp) to convert string to lower case and then match

```
$array=['admin','root'];
$role = strtolower($request->role);

if ( in_array($role,$array) ) {
   if( $role == 'admin') {
     //my logic
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have 1 word roles like in your example, and you only need to match your specified case and all lowercase, apply `ucfirst()` on the role.

```
$array=['Admin','Root'];
$role = ucfirst($request->role);

if(in_array($role,$array)){
if($role== 'Admin'){
     //my logic
  }
}
```

This will match `Admin` and `admin` but not `AdMiN` or any other casing.